# Don't understand, what it means : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: python, typeerror

Before I start describing problem, I need to say, that English isn't my native language, so , unfortunately, I can have a lot of mistakes. Thanks for understanding!

```
favourite_places = {
    'Paris':['Jake','Carl'],
    'London':'Jake',
    'Moscow':'Fred',
 }

for username,user_info in favourite_places.items():
    
print('======================')
    
print('Place: ' + username)
    
print('Who likes it: ' + user_info)
```

**Error:**

```
Type of error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I really don't now how to fix it. When I cleared `['Carl']`, the program starting working, but I need `['Carl']`. Please help

Comment: `['Jake', 'Carl']` is a list, and you can't use `+` between a string and a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your list items to make a string:

```
favourite_places = {
    'Paris':['Jake','Carl'],
    'London':['Jake'],
    'Moscow':['Fred']
 }

for username,user_info in favourite_places.items():
    print('======================')
    print('Place: ' + username)
    print('Who likes it: ' + ', '.join(user_info))
```

Comment: Nice one - that's my thing learnt for today - didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print "Who Likes it: [Jake, Carl]"

Unsurprisingly, python doesn't like that...

Try this:

```
favourite_places = {
'Paris':['Jake','Carl'],
'London':['Jake'],
'Moscow':['Fred'],
 }

for username,user_info in favourite_places.items():

    print('======================')

    print('Place: ' + username)
    
    users = ""
    for user in user_info:
        users = users + user + ", "
    users = users[:len(users)-2]   #Ach, sure we'll stick this in too to clean up the last trailing comma & space we don't want

    print('Who likes it: ' + users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all of your dictionary values lists, so that they can all be concatenated onto each other if needed:

```
favourite_places = {
    'Paris': ['Jake','Carl'],
    'London': ['Jake'],
    'Moscow': ['Fred'],
 }
```

and then when you need to print a list, use an f-string:

```
print(f'Who likes it: {user_info}')
```

Answer (score 0):

the Error statement say it all : you can only concatenate str (not "list") to str.

You *should* change your dictionary so that each value is a list to have consistent data to play with.

But, taking the lazy way, you *can* also simply use f-string as in the last line below :

```
for username,user_info in favourite_places.items():
    print('======================')
    print('Place: ' + username)
    print(f"Who likes it: {user_info}")
```

Output :

```
======================
Place: Paris
Who likes it: ['Jake', 'Carl']
======================
Place: London
Who likes it: Jake
======================
Place: Moscow
Who likes it: Fred
```